# Format menu bar time to english words

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, menu-bar, customization

I saw this screenshot of someone's menu bar and their time formatting is set in readable English.

[image: view menu bar: 'five to eleven']

Is this a this party app or a setting / script I can run on OS X?

Comment: Also shoutout to the source. Please check out http://madebybright.com.

Comment: Nice wolfram alpha app that runs in the menu. If you do much python, look at this framework: https://github.com/jaredks/rumps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a script to do this.

To show it in the menubar, use [BitBar](http://getbitbar.com). A small app which creates menubar items from shell script output.

[image: menubar demo]

Once you download BitBar, save the following code into a file called `lingualtime.1s.php` then point BitBar to where you saved it.

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php

<?php

# <bitbar.title>Lingual Clock</bitbar.title>
# <bitbar.version>v1.0</bitbar.version>
# <bitbar.author>Stan Hutcheon</bitbar.author>
# <bitbar.author.github>stnvh</bitbar.author.github>
# <bitbar.desc>displays the current time in a sentence</bitbar.desc>
# <bitbar.dependencies>php</bitbar.dependencies>

$time = array_map(function($time) {
    return intval($time);
}, explode(' ', date('g i')));

$st = array('hour' => '', 'minute' => '');

$past = '%s past %s'; $to = '%s to %s';

$pastHalf = false;

function get($int) {
    $numbers = array(
        1 => 'one', 2 => 'two', 3 => 'three', 4 => 'four', 5 => 'five', 6 => 'six', 7 => 'seven', 8 => 'eight', 9 => 'nine',
        11 => 'eleven', 12 => 'twelve', 13 => 'thirteen', 14 => 'fourteen', 15 => 'fifteen', 16 => 'sixteen', 17 => 'seventeen', 18 => 'eighteen', 19 => 'nineteen',
        10 => 'ten', 20 => 'twenty', 30 => 'thirty', 40 => 'fourty', 50 => 'fifty'
    );

    return isset($numbers[$int]) ? $numbers[$int] : '';
}

if($time[1] >= 35) {
    $pastHalf = true;

    $time[0] = $time[0] === 12 ? 1 : ++$time[0];
    $time[1] = 60 - $time[1];
}

# get lingual values
foreach(array('hour', 'minute') as $key => $part) {
    if($time[$key] < 20) {
        $st[$part] = get($time[$key]);
    } else {
        $currTenth = floor($time[$key] / 10) * 10;
        $currRem = $time[$key] - $currTenth;

        $ling = get($currTenth);
        if($ext = get($currRem)) {
            $ling .= '-' . $ext;
        }

        $st[$part] = $ling;
    }
}

printf(($pastHalf ? $to : $past) . PHP_EOL, $st['minute'], $st['hour']);
```

Comment: BitBar is telling me that it can't open files in the "PHP script" format.

Comment: You don't open it directly; Open BitBar, click on 'BitBar' in the menubar > preferences > open plugin folder. Then copy the saved file there.

Comment: Just an update on this answer, with the latest version of BitBar, you can install this functionality directly from BitBar's site: https://getbitbar.com/plugins/Time/fuzzyclock.1s.py

Answer (score 1):

I believe the app that you're looking for is called [World Time](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/world-time-in-words/id509085586?mt=12). It's a paid app ($1.99 USD) and should do everything that you want it to do. I don't know any free alternatives, though.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at FuzzyClock which is free but no longer maintained by the developers. I hosted the app in case someone else needs it. It still works on El Capitan: http://sayzlim.net/reading-time-on-mac-with-fuzzyclock/